# Why caused access denied when run delayed_job to aws?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, delayed-job

Now I am using Ruby on Rails framework. We use delayed_job to run a job to operate aws s3 file by aws-sdk. We deal with many files on aws s3.
When we run the job, we got this error:

```
e.message => Access Denied
e.backtrace.join("\n") =>
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.5.2/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:15:in `call'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.5.2/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/s3_sse_cpk.rb:19:in `call'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.5.2/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/s3_accelerate.rb:33:in `call'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.5.2/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_converter.rb:20:in `call'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.5.2/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/response_paging.rb:26:in `call'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.5.2/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:21:in `call'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.5.2/lib/seahorse/client/request.rb:70:in `send_request'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.5.2/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:207:in `block (2 levels) in define_operation_methods'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/aws-sdk-resources-2.5.2/lib/aws-sdk-resources/request.rb:24:in `call'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/aws-sdk-resources-2.5.2/lib/aws-sdk-resources/operations.rb:139:in `all_batches'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/aws-sdk-resources-2.5.2/lib/aws-sdk-resources/collection.rb:18:in `each'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/aws-sdk-resources-2.5.2/lib/aws-sdk-resources/collection.rb:18:in `each'
/app/releases/20161107014751/app/jobs/my_job.rb:35:in `perform'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activejob-5.0.0/lib/active_job/execution.rb:34:in `block in perform_now'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:448:in `block (2 levels) in around'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:286:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:257:in `with_locale'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activejob-5.0.0/lib/active_job/translation.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Translation>'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:391:in `instance_exec'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:391:in `block in make_lambda'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:285:in `block in halting'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `block in around'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:448:in `block (2 levels) in around'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:286:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activejob-5.0.0/lib/active_job/logging.rb:24:in `block (4 levels) in <module:Logging>'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activejob-5.0.0/lib/active_job/logging.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Logging>'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activejob-5.0.0/lib/active_job/logging.rb:44:in `block in tag_logger'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activejob-5.0.0/lib/active_job/logging.rb:44:in `tag_logger'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activejob-5.0.0/lib/active_job/logging.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Logging>'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:391:in `instance_exec'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:391:in `block in make_lambda'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:285:in `block in halting'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `block in around'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_perform_callbacks'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activejob-5.0.0/lib/active_job/execution.rb:33:in `perform_now'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activejob-5.0.0/lib/active_job/execution.rb:22:in `block in execute'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:448:in `block (2 levels) in around'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:286:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activejob-5.0.0/lib/active_job/railtie.rb:26:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:76:in `wrap'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:68:in `block in wrap'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:76:in `wrap'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:67:in `wrap'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activejob-5.0.0/lib/active_job/railtie.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:391:in `instance_exec'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:391:in `block in make_lambda'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:285:in `block in halting'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `block in around'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_execute_callbacks'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activejob-5.0.0/lib/active_job/execution.rb:20:in `execute'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activejob-5.0.0/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/delayed_job_adapter.rb:36:in `perform'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:84:in `block in invoke_job'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:81:in `invoke_job'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:230:in `block (2 levels) in run'
/usr/lib64/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:91:in `block in timeout'
/usr/lib64/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:230:in `block in run'
/usr/lib64/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:229:in `run'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:306:in `block in reserve_and_run_one_job'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:306:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:213:in `block in work_off'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:212:in `times'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:212:in `work_off'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:175:in `block (4 levels) in start'
/usr/lib64/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:174:in `block (3 levels) in start'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:173:in `block (2 levels) in start'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:172:in `loop'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:172:in `block in start'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ClearLocks>'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block (2 levels) in add'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block in add'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/worker.rb:171:in `start'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/command.rb:132:in `run'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/command.rb:120:in `block in run_process'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/application.rb:265:in `block in start_proc'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:84:in `call_as_daemon'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/application.rb:269:in `start_proc'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/application.rb:295:in `start'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/controller.rb:56:in `run'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons.rb:193:in `block in run_proc'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:88:in `catch_exceptions'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons.rb:192:in `run_proc'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/command.rb:118:in `run_process'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/command.rb:99:in `block in daemonize'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/command.rb:97:in `times'
/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.2/lib/delayed/command.rb:97:in `daemonize'
/app/current/bin/delayed_job:5:in `<main>'
```

I don't know whether it is the delayed_job problem or the aws-sdk problem, or s3 network problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For sure its related to AWS not with delayed job , you need to check your s3 creds or contact to them for more details**

[image]

Reference

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html